# Intuition for the minimal uncountable well-ordered set

Tags: general-topology

I have a couple questions about the long line and $S_\Omega$.

1. Geometrically, what is it?
2. Does every element have a predecessor and successor? I know that every section is countable, but I am unsure what that means in terms of pred and succ
3. If every element doesn't have a successor, which ones do? Does the smallest element have one?

Comment: "geometrically" it's nothing, because you cannot embed it into an Euclidean space. It's a sequence, only much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by your first question.  Every element in $S_\Omega$ has an immediate successor. However, not every element has an immediate predecessor.  For example, $\omega\in S_\Omega$ but it has no immediate predecessor, since $n<\omega$ but $n+1<\omega$ also.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. How do I picture $S_\Omega$ and the long line? I have trouble doing point-set proofs when there isn't a geometric argument. Also, what is $\omega$?

Comment: @Schmidt $\omega$ is the natural numbers (as an ordinal number).